# Change background image on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want the background image on my slider to change on mobile, when opened on mobile the part of the background that displays makes the slider text unreadable.

```css
@media (@max-width: 450px){
    .main_slider_item_bg {
        background-image:url("/images/web_phone.png")
    }
```

```html
<div class="owl-item main_slider_item">
<div class="main_slider_item_bg " style="background-image:url(images/web.png)"></div>
```

I've tried this but it's not working.

Comment: Why the `@` in front of `max-width`?

Comment: I'd remove the inline styling and set that in the class declaration, and also remove the `@` from the `@max-width: 450px` query declaration

Comment: the @ was an error

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is here:

```
@media (max-width: 450px){
    .main_slider_item_bg {
        background-image:url("/images/web_phone.png")
    }
}
```

Inside parentheses remenber put the device's feature with the syntax you use when you declare a CSS property inside a rule.

Comment: you can also set a min-width to media query as well @AjijolaHabeeb